# what is the path.resolve('.') output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

what will be the path if resolve('.') in node.js?

I went through the documentation of path npm. All I understood is resolve form the absolute path from right to left so it may include the current working directory for making absolute path and also remove the unwanted backslash or add if its need.

But nowhere it mention, what is the output for given below code?

In additional to that, i need to know "Can I passing the variable which holds path as string and if i can then what will happen if I pass the number variable?

```
var Path = require('path');
console.log(Path.resolve('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The output for that line will be the root of your project. I tried some different cases of running a node server from different directories.

my test.js is in `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\test.js`

if I run the server from Test directory the output will be `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\`

but if I go back one directory and run again the output will be `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\`

Now if we move to a real scenario in production with a hosted server that line will give you the complete path where your server is hosted. Let's say you have a `showImage(url)` function that takes an absolute path as a parameter and use it to show an image. You can get that url using Path variable like:

```
showImage(Path.resolve('.') + "\images\image.jpg");
```

Keep in mind this is just an example you can use it to refer to any file in your project.

For your second question this happens if you pass a path or multiple paths:

```js
path.resolve('/foo/bar', './baz');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz'

path.resolve('/foo/bar', '/tmp/file/');
// Returns: '/tmp/file'

path.resolve('wwwroot', 'static_files/png/', '../gif/image.gif');
// If the current working directory is /home/myself/node,
// this returns '/home/myself/node/wwwroot/static_files/gif/image.gif'
```

Comment: So you mean to say resolve('.') return the root path of my project and Do you have any idea about second question.

Comment: not the root path of your project but the rooth path from where the project is run from. As in my example the rooth path of my project was `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test\ ` ,  but where I ran it from a directory below the path I received was `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\ ` .  But when you deploy the code the line will probably return the root path.